# Javascript anchor target scrollTo top don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, page-jump

**Information**

I use target to change some CSS. That means I need to behaviour of target to continue to work. `preventDefault` might not be an option?

**Problem**

I expected the `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` would work to make the page jump to the top. That did not happend. Why not? Solution?

**jsfiddle**

You can try it out on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dmtN/1/). Scroll down to see the demo. I added padding.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#test">Test</a>
<div id="test">My content</div>
```

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
$("a").on("click", function(e){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: green;
}
#test:target {
    background: red;
}

a {
    padding-top: 1900px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer this one myself. I found out a solution that worked in all cases I tried. None of the other answers did.

http://jsfiddle.net/8dmtN/6/

**To prevent strange jumping**

- Avoid animate scrollTop

**Keep anchor state**

- Redirect it with window.location.
- Then scroll to top.

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var hash = $(this).attr('href');
        window.location = hash;
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: gr8! I suggest you accept your own answer. By that people can see that the question actually _is_ answered and also learn from your experience. because it is "trusted" / accepted.

Answer (score 3):

When you allready are using jQuery, I would do

```
$("a").on("click", function(e){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');
});
```

Comment: looks like a simple fix for issue regarding OP using :target pseudo class

Answer (score 1):

You need to do use [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method here to cancel the default action (navigation) of the click.

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#test').css('background-color', 'red')
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8dmtN/4/)

Comment: It don't work like before. The green is now still green after click. It switched to red before.